# The Quality of The Audio Downloaded from Web Service is not Good Enough

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android Application and the below method successfully downloads an audio/sound file from web service. But the sound **quality is not good** enough.
I test it both with emulator and a real device and also I play the downloaded file on **Mac Media Player** by the help of Eclipse File Explorer and I see the problem exists in all and so I think that the downloaded audio file has some problems. I also developed its iOS App and there is no problem there which means the web service works correctly.
Any help will be very much appreciated. 
Method parameters is as below

**URL** = https://xx.xxx.net/xfolder/webservice_method_name.php/

**query** = parameter1=somevalue1&_parameter2=somevalue2

```
public static String downloadFile(String URL, String query) {

    String result = "";
    try {
        URL myurl = new URL(URL);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes(query);
        output.close();

        MyManager sharedManager = MyManager.getInstance();

        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(sharedManager.appDirectory, ApplicationConstants.SOUND_FILE_NAME));

        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[output.size()];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            f.write(buffer);
        }
        f.close();

        result = "success";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("exception: ", e.getMessage());
        result = "failed";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It is not related with the downloadFile method/service. I set the android media player audio stream type as stream music.